# Parse API Crash Reporting for Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, crash, parse-platform, xamarin, analytics

Is there any way to integrate the Parse API Crash Reporting Analytics into Xamarin? There doesn't seem to be anything on the docs regarding it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you Xamarin Insights, is better analytics for Xamarin

Comment: is actually what I decided to go with! Thanks!

Comment: Xamarin Insights is out of Preview and is no longer strictly free. You get basic crash reporting with 7 days of rolling data with all platform subscriptions. To receive additional analytics, there's an additional subscription fee.

Comment: Yes @chrisriego, my bad. Insights not free anymore. But for analytics continue the better service for Xamarin. (For the moment)