# Crash reporting in Xamarin apps using Parse

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin

I wanted to report the crashing of my Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.Ios apps. I am not able to find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out on Stack Overflow: [Parse API Crash Reporting for Xamarin iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27428470/parse-api-crash-reporting-for-xamarin-ios)

I agree with the accepted answer and would recommend [Xamarin Insights](http://insights.xamarin.com).